# Is there any way to convert/read/import Geosoft Montaj grid in Mac OS?

Tags: mac, geosoft

I'd like to read data from a .grd file, made by [Oasis Geosoft Montaj](https://www.geosoft.com/products/oasis-montaj).

There is a free [viewer](https://www.geosoft.com/products/geosoft-viewer) that can convert to an ascii file, that can be read in e.g. QGIS, but the viewer program only works in Windows.

**Are there any options to import Geosoft grids on a Mac? Preferable free, open source.**

(It is not the same format as e.g. GMT .grd, which is a kind of netCDF.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Geosoft-Grid-Files-td5278481.html and https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4887 there is no chance since the format is propietary.

You might try a virtual box with Windows (or Linux+wine) OS to get the viewer running.

Comment: I think you are right, unfortunately. Will give the question a few before accepting this answer. Just in case...

Answer (score 0):

Thasnks to a few people, this QGIS plugin is now available. It works for single-band (non RGM) raster grids.

https://github.com/Loop3D/grd_loader

Comment: That should be (non RGB) not (non RGM)!