# Convert Geosoft GDB for use in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geosoft

I am looking to convert some Geosoft .gdbs for use in QGIS. The .gdb files are in Geosoft .gdb format and not in Esri File Geodatabase format. I do not have Geosoft installed (only QGIS) so am looking for a conversion workaround. I get errors when trying to import into QGIS as a vector/directory.

data here: http://www.geosciencebc.com/major-projects/quest/

Comment: the format is proprietary > https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303550/is-there-any-way-to-convert-read-import-geosoft-montaj-grid-in-mac-os (you would need a trial license or purchase)